# Triangle proportionality problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Problem is, given Fig1, If AB = 34, solve for CB.

[image]

My main difficulty with this problem is that I don't know how to correctly set a proportion with triangle ADB and triangle ADC.

If so, I could make a proportion between the sides of the triangles such that
X/Y = CB/34

where X and Y are just numbers, then I could easily solve for CB.

Maybe use Thales' theorem? If so, how? Any help is welcome.

Comment: maybe you can use law of sines

Comment: Using trigonometry will make this much easier. Are you permitted to use trig or do you need a purely geometric proof?

Comment: @Jaime *facepalm* yes of course.

Comment: @Jam any other way of solving it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I think there's no other obvious solution than a trigonometric one. The number $\sin 16^\circ / \sin 37^\circ$ should be algebraic but doesn't come up in any inverse symbolic calculator so it's probably not a very nice one to solve without trig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using law of sines in $\triangle ABC$, we have

$$\frac{AB}{\sin 127^{\circ}} = \frac{CB}{\sin16^{\circ}}$$

Hence,

$$CB = \frac{34 \sin16^{\circ}}{\sin127^{\circ}}$$

Comment: @user3490887 This solution is usefull for you?

Comment: Wait why AB/sin(37) wouldn’t it be AB/sin(53)?

Comment: sorry! It's better now